# fade.excludeTarget not working with findViewById

Tags: android, animation, mobile, android-transitions

I am adding some transition on my app but I am having an annoying flash effect on the Toolbar. The Toolbar that I am using is not an AppBar from the theme but an android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar that I added in my XML.
How can I get rid of the flash effect? So far I tried

```
    Transition fade = new Fade();
    View decor = getWindow().getDecorView();
    fade.excludeTarget(decor.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_container),true);
    fade.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
    fade.excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);
    fade.excludeTarget(findViewById(R.id.toolbarApp),true); //That's my Toolbar

    getWindow().setEnterTransition(fade);
    getWindow().setExitTransition(fade);
```

but it's not working.